# Addition of multiple arrays in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a number of arrays that I wish to broadcast into a single array using addition, which I know can be simply done such that:

```
a = numpy.array([1,2,3])
b = numpy.array9[4,5,6])
sum = a + b
print(sum)

[5,7,9]
```

However, I can't hardcode it like in this simple example as I will run my script numerous times with a different number of inputs and so will have a different number of arrays each time. Sometimes, I may have a and b, but other times I may have a, c and d but not b etc.

Using a loop I therefore append the arrays I do have into a list, so that I end up with something like:

```
newlist = [array([1,2,3,...5,4,3]), 
          array([5,7,2,...4,6,7]),
          array([3,6,2,...4,5,9])]
```

What would be the most pythonic way of getting a single array from the arrays in 'newlist' which is the addition of the arrays within it, such that (from newlist):

```
sum = [8,15,7,...14,15,19]
```

The arrays are all the same shape.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Stick with Numpy array and use its [`sum()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.sum.html) method:

```
>>> arr = np.array([[1,2,3,5,4,3], 
          [5,7,2,4,6,7],
          [3,6,2,4,5,9]])
>>> arr.sum(axis=0)
array([ 9, 15,  7, 13, 15, 19])
```

Of course you can do it with Python lists as well but it is going to be slow:

```
>>> lst = [[1,2,3,5,4,3], 
          [5,7,2,4,6,7],
          [3,6,2,4,5,9]]
>>> map(sum, zip(*lst))
[9, 15, 7, 13, 15, 19]
```

Answer (score 9):

There is no need to create a 2D array from your pre-existing 1D arrays. It will certainly not be faster than adding them together, e.g. using [`reduce`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce) with [`np.add`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.add.html#numpy.add):

```
In [14]: a = [np.random.rand(10) for _ in range(10)]

In [15]: %timeit np.array(a).sum(axis=0)
100000 loops, best of 3: 10.7 us per loop

In [16]: %timeit reduce(np.add, a)
100000 loops, best of 3: 5.24 us per loop
```

For larger arrays, it is even less advantageous:

```
In [17]: a = [np.random.rand(1000) for _ in range(1000)]

In [18]: %timeit np.array(a).sum(axis=0)
100 loops, best of 3: 6.26 ms per loop

In [19]: %timeit reduce(np.add, a)
100 loops, best of 3: 2.43 ms per loop
```

And of course:

```
In [20]: np.allclose(np.array(a).sum(axis=0), reduce(np.add, a))
Out[20]: True
```

Comment: Why not just use `sum`?

Comment: Good point... The only advantage of using `reduce` and `np.add` is that it will properly handle if one of the arrays in the list is not an ndarray, but a list. But if they are all guaranteed to be ndarrays, then yes, absolutely, `sum` is the best option.

Answer (score -1):

Here is another way:

```py
import numpy as np

arr1 = np.array([1,2,3,5,4,3])
arr2 = np.array([5,7,2,4,6,7])
arr3 = np.array([3,6,2,4,5,9])

out_arr = np.add(arr1, arr2)   
out_arr1 = np.add(out_arr, arr3) 
  
print("added array : ", out_arr1)  

# added array :  [ 9 15  7 13 15 19]
```

Comment: Your code would only work if there are exactly three arrays. The OP specifically said "not to hardcode" and that there "will be a different number of arrays each time".