# Sum sub array together

Tags: python, arrays, numpy-ndarray

I have an numpy array of 40 elements and for each element there are 500 elements.

I would like to sum each sub array like this.

```
 fourier[0] + fourier[1] + fourier[2] + ...
```

for example,

```
 fourier[0] = [0,1,2,3,4,5,...]
 fourier[1] = [2,3,4,5,6,8,...]
 fourier_sum = fourier[0] + fourier[1]
```

Thus, *fourier_sum =[2,4,6,8,10,13,...]*

However, it makes no sens to sum every sub array as above.

Is there another way ?

Thank you

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26279903/addition-of-multiple-arrays-in-python. The answers suggest a couple of ways to do it.

Comment: @slothrop, I removed my comment.

Comment: see this answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/26279972/20172954

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use the following which used a vectorized operation to sum each column to produce a 1-D array series then sums the series to give the total:

```
fourier_sum = np.sum(np.sum(fourier))
```

basic example:

```
fourier = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4], [4, 5, 6, 7], [8, 9, 10, 11]])
```

gives fourier_sum of 70